# Opencart 2.0.3.1 - Some products not showing up in category lists

Tags: php, opencart, categories, product, opencart2.x

In the Opencart admin area I have four categories (A B C D) and 20 products (1-20). I first created the categories and checked the Top box under data so that they would show up on the home page. I then created the products, 1-16 under category A, 17-18 under B, 19 under C, and 20 under D. However when I visit my store front, there are no products under C or D, and product 18 is missing from category B. Products 1-17 are all showing up where they should be.

I have SEO urls turned off, so this is not the root of the issue. The meta tag for all categories and products is set to "random" as I am still setting everything up.

Where should I begin troubleshooting in order to solve this issue? I tried adding some more products, and though I have added them to categories they still won't show up.

Comment: I'm not sure if this could be the problem, but product 17 (the last product that shows up) and product 18 (the first missing product) both accidentally got the same Model name. I changed it after entering the rest of the products, but nothing has changed and any new products I add still don't show up in the category listings.

Comment: what is the `route` parameter of that page in which there is undesirable behavior?

Comment: Somehow I managed to set the Date Available to tomorrow on product 18. Subsequent products all took tomorrows date as well. This can be closed now.

Comment: If you have an answer to your question, please write it in the answer section. You can also accept your own answer if you want to. Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the availability date. OpenCart now autopopulates it. If OpenCart can't find your time zone it defaults to UTC which can make the availability date the following day for some people.

Please assign previous availability and check its working proper.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the availability date. In that the date shall not exceed the current date. For example if today is 06-17-2016 and if we give 6-18-2016 in date_available, that particular product will not be counted and not displayed too, even though the product can be viewed from the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Also, Pre-Order items do not show on the category pages, which seems like a bug to me. On the Data tab from the edit product page there is a "Out of Stock Status" Setting which when set to Pre-order items do not show on the category page.